# django test doesn't populate request.auth

Tags: django, unit-testing, django-rest-framework

I made an endpoint called `/cars`. 
A person can create cars with a frontend, but devices *read* cars using an SDK, which has an API Key. This way, 2 rent-a-car companies can use the API without getting the cars mixed-up. Each app has its own API Key and its own person managing the contents.

This is being implemented with django restframework 3.x and django-oauth-toolkit.

I'm writing a test for a human retrieving cars, and another for a device.

This is failing:

```
def test_get_list(self):
    # devices have a django user (AUTH_USER_MODEL ---onetoone--- Device)
    self.client.force_authenticate(user=self.user_device)
    self._get_list()
    self.client.force_authenticate(user=None)
```

force_authentication sets request.auth to None. However, with postman or httpie, request.auth contains the Application object.

The queryset is:

```
def get_queryset(self):
    if hasattr(self.request.user, 'device'):
        # get the cars created by the owner of the API Key
        return self.request.auth.application.user.cars.all()
    return self.request.user.cars.all() # get my cars
```

1. Does this approach in the queryset make sense?
2. Am I testing it in the wrong way?
3. Why is request.auth empty? Is force_authentication using BasicAuthentication?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. I would recommend going with `check_object_permission` for this kind of checks. You can read more [here](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/permissions/#object-level-permissions).
2. DRF documentation states that you need to force_authenticate the request if you are using `APIRequestFactory`. From the [documentation](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/testing/#forcing-authentication):

   ```
   from rest_framework.test import force_authenticate

   factory = APIRequestFactory()
   user = User.objects.get(username='olivia')
   view = AccountDetail.as_view()

   # Make an authenticated request to the view...
   request = factory.get('/accounts/django-superstars/')
   force_authenticate(request, user=user)
   response = view(request)
   ```

   To authenticate with `APIClient` try using `credentials`. Example from the [documentation](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/testing/#authenticating):

   ```
   from rest_framework.authtoken.models import Token
   from rest_framework.test import APIClient

   # Include an appropriate `Authorization:` header on all requests.
   token = Token.objects.get(user__username='lauren')
   client = APIClient()
   client.credentials(HTTP_AUTHORIZATION='Token ' + token.key)
   ```
3. The same is the second question.

Comment: things make so much sense all of a sudden. thanks! I got it working.

Answer (score 1):

As pointed in the [documentation](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/testing/#force_authenticateusernone-tokennone) force_authenticate bypass authentication therefore it's your job to simulate the missing authentication part, including filling the request.auth.

Otherwise, you'll need to configure a data set and call either login or credential on the APIClient instance.